Flutter audioplayers duration is inaccurate and not working
When using the Flutter audioplayers package, the audio duration is not accurate and displays as the wrong shorter length than the actual duration of the Audio file when played through other audio players (such as iTunes)

I have been trying to solve this bug for some time, until I realised after much effort, it was an issue with the Audio file itself and the bit rate. Make sure that the bit rate is a constant or fixed bit rate, NOT a variable bit rate, or VBT, as can be known. As soon as I changed the Audio file from VBT to a fixed bit rate, it worked as expected.
